# Problem with Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: database, primary-key

I have a question - I am now copying a large amount of data from one db to another - the databases are identical, they have the same names, columns, etc.

```
 INSERT INTO [Db].[schema].[table] ([id],[name],[kod],[number])
SELECT [id],[name],[kod],[number]
FROM [MYLINKEDSRVR\Test].[Db].[schema].[table]
EXCEPT
SELECT [id],[name],[kod],[number]
FROM [Db].[schema].[table];
```

Twenty tables converted without much difficulty.

Now I have this problem.

*Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ui'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'schema.table'. The duplicate key value is (770132, Jul  1 2011 16:00AM).*

**Can you help me with this?**

I try one more script

```
INSERT INTO [Db].[schema].[table] ([id],[name],[kod],[number])
SELECT [id],[name],[kod],[number]
FROM [MSDBS-JKT\TDETest].[Db].[schema].[table] AS source
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM [Db].[schema].[table] AS target
  WHERE target.[kod] = source.[kod]
  AND target.[nazev] = source.[nazev]
);
```

Then I continued with the other columns. They all succeeded except for the last two, which again failed.

*Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 30
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ui'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'schema.table'. The duplicate key value is (37788, Jan  1 1800 14:00AM).*

**Can you help me with this?**

Comment: Ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're inserting the same value more that once and you cannot do that since it's the primary key:

- in the first example the duplicate data is `(770132, Jul 1 2011 16:00AM)`
- in the second example the duplicate data is `(37788, Jan 1 1800 14:00AM)`

You can solve it in mutiple ways:

- pre-processing the data before inserting into the DB and removing the duplicate values
- not specifying the primary key `PK_ui` of the database
- [merging data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16) to indicate how to solve handle and solve primary key conflict when heppen